# How to make a custom discount to work correctly

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, ce-1.6.2.0

I am trying to build a extension which will give discount to a customer if he/she have like the facebook like button on the site, and i am not sure where and what should i do to accomplish this task.

I have prepared this checklist for this.
1) I will get user email from Facebook some how if they clicked the like button.
2) Then match this email against the logged in user if a match is found the customer is going to get discount.

Now from here what should i do give proper discount to that particular customer only, should i create a coupon pragmatically one per customer basis and apply that for current checkout or should i email this to customer for using their discount reward later on date.

Anybody having any idea on this ??

Answer (score 1):

We implemented something like this for twitter: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/DiscountForATweet

Most of the things won't help you, but maybe the rule implementation helps you.

Comment: Maybe add in the rule implementation piece that might help give some direction?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the [Gift for New Customer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gift-for-new-customer.html) extension can help you.
It's an extension that allows you to gift a simple or virtual product to a customer placing it directly in their basket.

There might be some code you can reuse for your discount extension

Comment: Please add a few more words about the extension

Comment: Exactly Sander Mangel. You are almost correct. Thanks.